# Can node.js be used without installing anything on the machine?

Tags: node.js, dvd

I'm interested in a webserver solution, where nothing needs to be installed on the machine itself. So you just insert the (eg) DVD and of you go.

I know that products exist that allow this, but can it be done with Node.js?

EDIT: I would like the DVD to work on a machine already running some OS (eg. Windows or MacOS), so basically have a cross platform webserver running only from a DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can use a Linux live CD in your favorite flavor and follow the flow the maintainers of that live CD are proposing for changes and install your node.js packages inside it. That would give you a live CD (or DVD) with your node.js application…

Here is an example customizing an Ubuntu live CD to install a BitCoin miner on it: [www.greenone.org](http://www.greenone.org/2012/10/09/how-to-customize-your-own-ubuntu-live-cd-for-bitcoin-mining/) - If you adapt that and install the node.js packages instead of the miner you would have your live CD…

Comment: Yes, you're right! However (sorry I did'nt mention this originally), I would like to be able to put the DVD into a machine already running eg. Windows or some MacOs. Would this be possible?

Comment: You talk about not to reboot the machine to load the live CD? I don't think so. You'd need an autoloader for all different OSses or even binaries for all OSses… I don't even know an autoloader approach for OSX so you'd have to start the web server manually… - Maybe one can build a small web server runnable from CD but not as an easy-to-use solution.

Comment: Theoretically you could put a [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) file to the CD together with Ansible / Puppet directives to set up a vagrant box… This would only require VirtualBox and Vagrant on the host system…